# OS X server Open Directory fail over successfully but not the user home directories

Tags: openldap, mac, failover, mac-osx-server, home-directory

We setup the OS X server Open Directory(OD) master and replica. Users are created on master and their home directories are on the master server. When the master OD server is down, the OD client (MAC) will automatically use the OD replica for authentication. This part works. But the OD client will still try to read the home directory on master and because master is down, this operation will fail. We are looking for a solution to make the home directory failover work. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to setup a common storage that both can access at the same time, even when one goes down.  I think you can point users' home directory to a network path, in which case you can setup a third system just for broadcasting the storage or a NAS.  Otherwise, if they needs to see the storage as local, then you can look into setting up a SAN or MetaSAN.  Hope that helps.